# Why doesn't setJMenuBar() trigger ContainerEvent?

Tags: java, swing

Any work-arounds?

```
myContainer.getContentPane().addContainerListener(new ContainerListener(){
    @Override public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getChild().getClass().getName().toString());
}});
myContainer.add(new JPanel());
myContainer.setJMenuBar(new JMenuBar());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JMenuBar is not part of the content pane.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Top Level Containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) for information about the structure of the frame and its components.

The actual code in the setJMenuBar() method is:

```
getRootPane().setMenuBar(menubar);
```

So I would guess the ContainerListener would need to be added to the root pane.

Edit:

From the tutorial link you can see that the frame structure looks like:

- root pane

  - layered pane

    - menu bar
    - content pane

from the code I posted it looks like the menubar is added to the root pane which is why I suggested adding the container listener to the root pane. However it appears you need to add the ContainerListener to the layered pane:

```
getLayeredPane().addContainerListener(new ContainerAdapter()...
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wasn't aware of the difference. If you are suggesting I change myContainer.getContentPane() to myContainer.getRootPane().addContainerListener(), it didn't work. But nice guess